# how to read VBR audio in novacaine (as opposed to PCM)

Tags: objective-c, core-audio, signal-processing, accelerate-framework

The creator of [novacaine](https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine#readme) offered example code where audio data is read from a a file and fed to a ring buffer. When the file reader is created though, the output is forced to be PCM:

```
- (id)initWithAudioFileURL:(NSURL *)urlToAudioFile samplingRate:(float)thisSamplingRate numChannels:(UInt32)thisNumChannels
{

...

    // We're going to impose a format upon the input file
    // Single-channel float does the trick.
    _outputFormat.mSampleRate = self.samplingRate;
    _outputFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    _outputFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat;
    _outputFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 4*self.numChannels;
    _outputFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    _outputFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 4*self.numChannels;
    _outputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = self.numChannels;
    _outputFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 32;

}
```

I'm trying to contribute to the novacaine project by allowing it to

- Read from the iPod library (which can only be accessed via AVAssetReader, rather than the audio file services library)
- Read and write VBR packets rather than PCM.

So this is what my equivalent function of the above looks like (see the NOTE: parts)

```
- (id)initWithAudioAssetURL:(NSURL *)urlToAsset samplingRate:(float)thisSamplingRate numChannels:(UInt32)thisNumChannels
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {

        // Zero-out our timer, so we know we're not using our callback yet
        self.callbackTimer = nil;

        // Open a reference to the audio Asset Track and setup the reader
        self.assetURL = urlToAsset;
        AVURLAsset *songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:self.assetURL options:nil];
        NSError * error = nil;
        AVAssetReader* reader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:songAsset error:&error];
        AVAssetTrack* track = [songAsset.tracks objectAtIndex:0];

        //NOTE: we use the track's native settings here, as opposed to forcing it to be PCM
        //like the example above
        _readerOutput = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:track
                                                                  outputSettings:NULL];

        _nativeTrackASBD = [self getTrackNativeSettings:track];

        [reader addOutput:_readerOutput];
        [reader startReading];


        // Set a few defaults and presets
        self.samplingRate = thisSamplingRate;
        self.numChannels = thisNumChannels;
        self.latency = .011609977; // 512 samples / ( 44100 samples / sec ) default

        // Arbitrary buffer sizes that don't matter so much as long as they're "big enough"
        self.outputBufferSize = 100000; //buffer sample sizes vary around 60-70k, we keep it @ 100k to be safe
        self.numSamplesReadPerPacket = 8192;
        self.desiredPrebufferedSamples = self.numSamplesReadPerPacket*2;

        //NOTE: these buffers are float, where as the above audio code is in SInt16
        self.outputBuffer = (float *)calloc(2*self.samplingRate, sizeof(float));
        self.holdingBuffer = (float *)calloc(2*self.samplingRate, sizeof(float));


        // Allocate a ring buffer (this is what's going to buffer our audio)
        ringBuffer = new RingBuffer(self.outputBufferSize, self.numChannels);


        // Fill up the buffers, so we're ready to play immediately
        [self bufferNewAudioFromAsset];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Looking at the code, it seems that everything is made in float (the audio buffers, the output format etc).. Is there a reason for this? (Keep in mind that the iOS audio canonical format is in SInt16, *not* float).. for example see in the Novocaine::renderCallback function:

```
else if ( sm.numBytesPerSample == 2 ) // then we need to convert SInt16 -> Float (and also scale)
{
    float scale = (float)INT16_MAX;
    vDSP_vsmul(sm.outData, 1, &scale, sm.outData, 1, inNumberFrames*sm.numOutputChannels);

    for (int iBuffer=0; iBuffer < ioData->mNumberBuffers; ++iBuffer) {  

        int thisNumChannels = ioData->mBuffers[iBuffer].mNumberChannels;

        for (int iChannel = 0; iChannel < thisNumChannels; ++iChannel) {
            vDSP_vfix16(sm.outData+iChannel, sm.numOutputChannels, (SInt16 *)ioData->mBuffers[iBuffer].mData+iChannel, thisNumChannels, inNumberFrames);
        }
    }

}
```

What are the list of things that I gotta change to make this library compatible with reading and writing VBR Data?

A

Comment: were you able to conclude anything since you edited your question? I am working on an iOS audio project using the Novacaine library as well. My thoughts are that float is most likely being used because it is the preferred way of manipulating sample data (for instance in my case, implementing a real time granular synthesis method). It just makes more sense to do so from a DSP standpoint. I came across [this blog](http://chritto.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/processing-avplayers-audio-with-mtaudioprocessingtap/) that discusses the new iOS 6 `MTAudioProcessingTap`. Not sure if this helps you..

Comment: i remember concluding back then what you have concluded: that the authors wanted to normalize all their audio into a float format b/c it's the preferred way for DSP (i have since abandoned pursuing novacaine as a potential solutio). Thanks for the library though I found it very useful.

Comment: Did you get novocaine working with iPod library items?

Comment: @Mr.Russian unfortunately I haven't touched this code for a while

Comment: I just checked and it looks like the library now plays songs from the iPod library. Did you by any chance make an equalizer using this library?